# How to Import column from xlsx > Create Json Array > Update SQLite DB

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I need help converting the xlsx or a csv file into something that looks like the example below so that I could import it into SQLite.

```
Stocks_Update = [
    {'stock_ticker' : 'TSLA'},
    {'stock_ticker' : 'MSFT'},
    {'stock_ticker' : 'AAPL'},
    {'stock_ticker' : 'GOOG'},
    {'stock_ticker' : 'FB'},
    {'stock_ticker' : 'SQ'},
    
]
```

The columns looks like this in excel

[image]

I have found a way to import it using

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
ftypes = [(".xlsm","*.xlsx",".xls")]
ttl  = "Title"
dir1 = 'C:\\'
filePath=r"C:\Users\home\Desktop\code_projects\FIRE_Dashboard\stock_ticker.xlsx"
#filePath = askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes, initialdir = dir1, title = ttl)
```

The tutorial where I found this makes the imported file into a pandas dataframe. But I need to make that array instead.

```
stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath)
stocklist=stocklist.head()

exportList= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock', "RS_Rating", "50 Day MA", "150 Day Ma", "200 Day MA", "52 Week Low", "52 week High"])
```

So that I could import it into SQLite using

```
def update_Stocks():
    for data_point in Stocks_Update:

        try:
            Stocks.create(stock_ticker=data_point['stock_ticker'])
        except IntegrityError:
            update_record = Stocks.get(stock_ticker=data_point['stock_ticker'])
            update_record.stock_ticker = data_point['stock_ticker']
            update_record.save()
```

I am completely lost on where to even get started, as I am not even sure if the thing I need as a final result is a json array or not but it looks similar. Any help on how to do this is much appreciated along with helping a noobie with the correct terminology. Maybe if I knew what it was called I would be able to find a guide for it online.

Anyway thanks again :)

Comment: If you have a CSV file with your data, no need to resort to python to import it into a sqlite database. Just use the sqlite3 command line program: https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Comment: Thank you for that link, I will check it out right now :)

Comment: Thanks again, was able to figure out how to import CSV using that and another documentation i found :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to find a way on how to do it with python code but found a workaround with

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/